# How to use conditional aggregation on columns which have multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

I need to generate an output to show different role(from table2) as separate columns for an id(from table 1), but the role is not mandatory to be present in the table 2 and sometimes there can be multiple roles also. I am stuck here.

I have tried coalesce, but with that I am not able to get the multiple values into different column

```
SELECT 
i.id,
i.name,
COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN r.ID = i.id THEN r.Role END), 'NA') AS Role,
COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN r.Role = rl.Role THEN rl.value END), 'NA') AS value,
COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN r.Role = rl.Role   THEN rl.value_2 END), 'NA') AS value_2
```

FROM 
    employee_id AS i
    LEFT JOIN employee_role r ON r.id = i.id
    LEFT JOIN Role rl ON r.role = rl.role
GROUP BY 
    i.id,
    i.name

Please find the table structure below:

Table 1: Employee_id
ID  Name
100021  Bob
100023  Tom
100024  Jim

Table 2: Employee_Role
ID  Role
100023  user1
100024  Beta_user
100024  user

Table 3: Role
Role         value  value_2
Beta_user    zz         56
user         23         ss
user1        sd         45

Required_Result
ID      Name    Role      value  value_2
100021  Bob     NA    NA     NA
100023  Tom     user1     sd     45
100024  Jim     Beta_user zz     56
100024  Jim     user      23     ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no aggregation is necessary:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, er.role,
       COALESCE(rl.value, 'NA') AS value,
       COALESCE(rl.value_2, 'NA') AS value_2
FROM employee_id e LEFT JOIN
     employee_role er
     ON er.id = e.id LEFT JOIN
     Role r
     ON er.role = r.role;
```